# get value from different document

Tags: xml, xslt

I've the below piece of XML.

```
<toc-div>
  <title>CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION</title>
  <subtitle>
    <content-style font-style="italic">David Smith</content-style>
  </subtitle>
  <toc-item>
    <toc-title>1. Love on the Star Ferry</toc-title>
    <toc-pg>2</toc-pg>
  </toc-item>
  <toc-item>
    <toc-title>2. Contracts, Torts, Copyrights and Other Mysteries of the Legal World</toc-title>
    <toc-pg>2</toc-pg>
  </toc-item>
</toc-div>
```

Here actually I want to get the reference that matches the title from different document.

The second document i have is

```
<chapter num="1">
  <toc>
    <toc-part>
      <toc-div>
        <toc-item>
          <toc-title>1. Love on the Star Ferry</toc-title>
          <toc-pg>1.002</toc-pg>
        </toc-item>
        <toc-item>
          <toc-title>2. Contracts, Torts, Copyrights and Other Mysteries of the Legal World</toc-title>
          <toc-pg>1.004</toc-pg>
        </toc-item>
      </toc-div>
    </toc-part>
  </toc>
</chapter>
```

The condition is that first the title should be matched in both cases and then the `<toc-pg>` should be taken and displayed. I'm able to redirect to that document by using the below xslt, but I'm unable to know how I can retrieve these values. Below is the XSLT I tried.

```
<xsl:template match="toc-item">
  <xsl:variable name="prent">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(../title,' '),' ')"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="tex">
    <xsl:value-of select="./toc-title/text()"/>
  </xsl:variable>    
  <xsl:variable name="cha">
   <xsl:value-of select="$prent"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:if test="document(concat('C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\HK\Business Law in Hong Kong\Source\Business Law in Hong Kong/Chapter ',$cha,'.xml'))/chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item/toc-title/text() = ./toc-title/text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$tex"/>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat('C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\HK\Business Law in Hong Kong\Source\Business Law in Hong Kong/Chapter ',$cha,'.xml'))/chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item/toc-title" mode="x"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Please let me know how can I see the value expected. The documents are as follows [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/4fNiHjVv) and [XML](http://pastebin.com/5T7Q5KLS)

Comment: Include more of your XSLT stylesheet, otherwise its difficult to say where you err. For instance, which other templates have `mode='x'`?

Comment: Hi @MathiasMüller, as of now mode is not defined. and thanks for responding. i've updated my question with pastebin link containing all the xslt

Comment: I indented your code to make it more readable. Usually, it's not a good idea to include links to code fragments outside StackOverflow because this prevents the question from being self-contained. As soon as the links become obsolete the questions will be very difficult to understand. As an effort from your side could you reduce your external input XML and XSLT to the bare minimum and include it explicitly into your answer? Since you are working with absolute paths it would be one prerequisite that you include all bracing tags from the root element. I think then you will be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the question is titled "get value from different document", the posted code already contains the "document()" command which accomplishes this.
The real question seems to be "how to add a filter on the apply-templates select". This is done using square brackets like so:

```
<xsl:template match="your_element">
  <xsl:variable name="filter" select="id"/>
  ... other stuff ...
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file.xml')/diff_element[diff_id=$filter]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of setting up a variable you can use a value of the current element using "current()". I used general element names instead of your actual ones because this way it is more obvious what happens.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for responding, can you please let me know how i can add a filter for above quetion. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2423959: Your 3rd-last line should be (attention: template for "toc-item" instead "toc-title" needed as only this makes sense, you already know the toc-title because this is the filter): <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat('C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\HK\Business Law in Hong Kong\Source\Business Law in Hong Kong/Chapter ',$cha,'.xml'))/chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item[toc-title=current()/toc-title]" mode="x"/>

Comment: Hi @Andreas can we chat on this please. i'm unable to know how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the if condition should be changed to

```
<xsl:if test="document(concat('C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\HK\Business Law in Hong Kong\Source\Business Law in Hong Kong/Chapter ',$cha,'.xml'))/chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item/toc-title/text() = ./toc-title/text()">

            <xsl:value-of select="document(concat('C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\HK\Business Law in Hong Kong\Source\Business Law in Hong Kong/Chapter ',$cha,'.xml'))/chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item[toc-title=$tex]/toc-pg" />

        </xsl:if>
```

Thanks all for your help.

Thanks